# Why script returning Error with this code in php?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I am trying to convert a file name into a binary data type by using sqlsrv and save it in a mysql database but I receive this error:

> fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect

My PHP code is:

```
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","musiccloud");

if(!empty($_FILES['file'])){
  $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $image =$ext;
  Echo"File Copied Successfully";
  sqlsrv_query($conn, 'INSERT INTO musiclist(name) VALUES (?)', array(
    array($ext, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING, 
          SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_BINARY)
  ));

  echo "successfully uploaded";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You state that your trying to insert to mysql - but are using sqlsrv_query 
this is for MS Sql Server try http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

you used mysqli driver to connect to your DB that can only connect to MySQL/MariaDB.

if you are using SQL Server then you have to use `PDO` or `sqlsrv_connect` in your case.

Comment: i am Using Mysql

Comment: @Eddy then you must use mysqli_query() instead of sqlsrv_query() (because you are using mysqli driver

Comment: @Eddy then use mysqli_query rather than sqlsrv_query