# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mssql_query()

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am trying to connect PHP with mssql and facing this error.
I have downloaded the drivers and installed and configured my PHP.ini file as well.
I am receiving connection established but its not working for mssql_query can any body please help me on this.

```
<?php
$serverName = "server details";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=> "mydbname", "UID" => "id", "PWD" => "password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName , $connectionInfo);

if($conn){
    echo "connection established <br />";
}
else{
    echo "connection could not established <br />";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM AgeNames";

$result = mssql_query( $query );

for ($i = 0; $i < mssql_num_rows( $result ); ++$i)
     {
         $line = mssql_fetch_row($result);
         print( "$line[0] - $line[1]\n");
     }
```

I have added these fields in PHP ini
[PHP ini image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1bK7.png)

and this is what i am getting in phpinfo()

[phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiyXV.png)

[phpinfo screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0Z0E.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17498216/2943403

Comment: @mickmackusa it is not MySQL

Comment: @mickmackusa I am asking for mssql, the provided link by you have solution for mysql

Comment: That's why I didn't use that post to hammer yourcquestion closed.  The rationale is the same though.  You cannot mix APIs.

Comment: Evidently, it is appropriate to close this page using the earlier mentioned duplicate.  Here is another snowflake: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49473909/2943403

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're using incorrect functions.
You need to use `sqlsrv_query` function instead of `mssql_query` i.e.

```sql
$result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query );
```

P.S. 
`mssql_query` has been removed since PHP 7.0. Read more [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php).

Comment: Thanks a lot but I am facing another issue by using sqlsrv_query I am not able to fetch data from tables.

`$query = "SELECT * FROM AgeNames";

$result = sqlsrv_query(  $conn ,  $query);

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))    
{    
     echo "Minimum Age: ".$row['0']."\n";    
     echo "Maximum Age: ".$row['MaxAge']."\n";    
} `

and I am getting this error
`Notice: Undefined index: MinAge in C:\xampp\htdocs\aljawaizi\connection.php on line 23
Minimum Age:
Notice: Undefined index: MaxAge in C:\xampp\htdocs\aljawaizi\connection.php on line 24`

Comment: Hi @KhalilUrRehman, I suggest you create a different question for this error. Since this doesn't pertain to the original question as you're no longer getting `Call to undefined function`, this means your code was able to process that funciton.

Comment: Why in the world would you specify NUMERIC keys in the result set, then try to access a key called `MaxAge`?